# How to plot subsets of data

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I'm working with some data in Mathematica,and I'm trying to minimise the commands I need to use.

I'm currently using the code:

```
a = Import["file location", {"Data", {All}, {4, 5}}]
```

To import data from columns 4 and 5 of a csv file and then plot using

```
ListLinePlot[a]
```

Each file contains more than one set of data I would like to plot. I would like to read in all the data from one file, and then only plot certain columns of it at once. Something like this:

```
a = Import["file location", {"Data", {All}, {4, 5, 10, 11}}]
ListLinePlot[a{{All},{4,5}}]
```

Such that it plots only the data contained in columns 4 and 5.

This is probably just a syntactic error or something due to my limited Mathematica knowledge. Ultimately this is not a huge issue as I can just import each set individually, but it would make things much simpler in terms of the number of objects I need to manage.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Import["data.csv"];

ListLinePlot[a[[All, {4, 5}]]]

ListLinePlot[a[[All, {1, 2}]]]
```

etc.